# How to regularly update mongoose db in express js without req

Tags: express, mongoose

I want to retrieve 'Content' instances sorted by a ranking factor, which changes by likes, dislikes and time. First solution I came up was adding 'ranking factor' virtual field on the 'Content' model, but mongoose didn't allow me to sort the instances by the virtual field when retrieving them. So the only solution I have now is adding 'ranking factor' field on the model and update all content instances regularly using setTimeOut function of node js. Then where should I add setTimeOut function in express js structure?

I considered adding setTimeOut(2000, // update all content instances here) on app.js file, but there was a feeling that it is not somewhat right. I'm planning to add the codes like below.

setTimeOut(2000, Content.findAndUpdate(*, {rankingFactor: calculateRankingFactorWithTime(window.currentDate, this.likes, this.dislike}))

Comment: If my initial approach doesn't seem right. Can anyone tell me better way how to retrieve model instances sorted by a ranking factor? Problem is  this ranking factor changes with time.

Comment: Have you tried querying with `aggregate` which would let you compute your ranking factor server-side and then sort by it?

Comment: I will try it right away thank you!

Comment: But is it possible to use sqrt and log function in aggregation 'add fields'  section? To compute the ranking factor, I have to use those math modules.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with the `$sqrt` and `$log` expression operators. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-expression-operators

Comment: appreciated! Thank you so much!!